# In Descartes "Meditations on First Philosophy", what does the title "first philosophy" mean?

Tags: descartes

"Meditations" as outlined in his book refers to methods of acquiring knowledge, but what does "First philosophy" refer too/mean?

It certainly does not carry a sequential meaning, because there is no "Second" philosophy..

Comment: You can see the relevant discssion in Kurt Brandhorst, [Descartes' Meditations on First Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=Uaka-23Zjs0C&pg=PA8), (2010), page 8-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "metaphysics". He uses the same terminology as Aristotle. In modern (and more specific terms), we can also construe it as "ontology"; that is, the study of being is the most basic ("first") philosophy.